# Search JSON file for record and append to dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, spyder

I have a very large json file (3m+ records) that causes memory issues when I try to import it using pandas.

```py
data = pd.read_json("JSON_large_file.json")
```

This procedure causes problem when the file exceeds 100k records.

In order to get around this issue, I would like open the file, and search the record for an identifier (e.g. Customer_Number), and then append it to a dataframe.

Is this possible, and how could it be done?

Comment: Have you considered reading the file in chunks instead? The `pandas` read functions have the optional parameter `chunksize`.

Comment: Not familiar with that function. Will have a look